# Cannot implicitly convert 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, timespan

The below code works fine :

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
int d3 = (int)(d1 - d2).TotalDays;
```

But what if I define `DateTime` as `DateTime?` :

```
DateTime? d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
int d3 = (int)(d1 - d2).TotalDays;
```

underlined red with error

> Cannot implicitly convert 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Is it possible to get the difference of number of days between two datetimes that are defined as nullable?

Comment: `int d3 = (int)(d1.Value - d2.Value).TotalDays;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well yes, but you need to use the `Value` property to "un-null" it:

```
int d3 = (int)(d1 - d2).Value.TotalDays;
```

However, you should consider the possibility that either `d1` or `d2` is null - which won't happen in your case, but could in other cases. You may want:

```
int? d3 = (int?) (d1 - d2)?.TotalDays;
```

That will give a result of `null` if either `d1` or `d2` is `null`. This is assuming you're using C# 6, of course - otherwise the `?.` operator isn't available.

(You could use `GetValueOrDefault()` in the first case as suggested by user3185569, but that would silently use an empty `TimeSpan` if either value is `null`, which feels unlikely to be what you want.)

Comment: The use of `GetValueOrDefault()` is a reasonable optimisation of the code given and applicable to other cases where the nullable is known to not be null (most often when following a branch on testing precisely that), but like all optimisations, knowing when not to use it is more important than knowing the micro-opt it gives.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using `GetValueOrDefault()`:

```
DateTime? d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
int d3 = (int)(d1 - d2).GetValueOrDefault().TotalDays;
```

`d1 - d2` return Nullable TimeSpan which doesn't directly contains a property called `TotalDays`. But using `GetValueOrDefault()` you can return a `TimeSpan` object and get 0 Total Days if the value was `NULL`

If you do really expect `Null` Values, it is better to differentiate between 0 days (What the above approach returns) and and invalid operation (date - null), (null - date) and (null - null). Then you might need to use another approach:

```
int? d3 = (int) (d1 - d2)?.TotalDays;
```

Or if you're using a version prior to C# 6 :

```
int? d3 = d1.HasValue && d2.HasValue ? (int)(d1 - d2).Value.TotalDays : new int?();
```

Comment: This is kind of neat code, but the OP would have to understand that `null - null = 0` which probably isn't true. It would probably be better if `null - null = null`.

Comment: @Enigmativity You're right. But what i understood from the OP is that the dates are valid but are just defined as `Nullable`. Otherwise, it makes perfect sense to differentiate between 0 days of difference and an invalid operation.

Answer (score 0):

use long and convert

```
long x
System.TimeSpan y= new TimeSpan(x);
```